# How do I optimize a custom post type admin page with 25,000 posts?

Tags: admin, mysql, optimization

I'm getting the occasional excessive resource limit error to due to loading so many posts at once. We had set the PHP limit to 128 but just loading the list of posts for a couple of the post types is taking up even more resources than that.

On the admin page with 25,000 posts, there are 217 queries and on another admin page with 15,000 posts there are 301 queries.

Is there a way to cache these or perhaps another solution to loading these pages without an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Trying using the Object Cache plugin discussed at: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/09/how-to-speed-up-the-wordpress.php

Another tip would be to install php-apc; see: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/09/hack-of-the-day-speeding-up-wordpress-on-a-vps.php

Hope this helps!